# Why does an object fly down at high speed when using Vector2.Lerp?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I try to use Vector2.Lerp in unity, I run into a problem. The object flies downwards at a very high speed.

I am trying to make a moving platform in a 2D game. It moves from minimum x value to maximum x value. I want to use Vector2.Lerp to make the speed in both directions the same, but when I apply transform.Translate, and pass Vector2.Lerp as argument, the object flies down with very high speed.

That's the problem, because when I pass in Vector 3 with coordinates divided by 100, everything works fine. But different speeds appear in different directions.

The object has a box collider 2D and a script that moves it. It has no rigidbody 2D.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my function that moves the object in one direction (it's called in FixedUpdate):

```
Vector2 target = new Vector3(xMin, 0);

Vector2 moving = Vector2.Lerp(transform.position, target, speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

transform.Translate(moving);
```

Comment: `Excuse me please, I can't add images, so I have to write the code in text.` You're *supposed* to write the code in text, *not* add images of code.

Comment: The 3rd param of Lerp is the value used to interpolate between a and b.  It should start at 0 and move towards 1.  Value 0 will return the first params value, 1 will return the second params value, 0.5 will return a position in between those values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73857670/7111561) `Lerp` interpolates linear from the given start value to he target value using a relative factor from `0` to `1`.

You can go with a Coroutine but would need to start it and make sure it is running only once at a time.

Or if you simply want to continuously move towards the target you would want to rather use

```
private void Update()
{
    transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, new Vector2(xMin, 0), speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

---

Another note for your usecase: If you use `Rigibody`/`Rigidbody2D` or any other component form the physics engines you do **not** want to move anything via `Transform` as this breaks with the physics, usually looks weird and breaks collision detection etc.

You rather want to go though the according component - in your case e.g.

```
[SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D _rigidbody;

pivate void Awake()
{
    if(!_rigidbody) _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    var position = Vector2.MoveTowards(_rigidbody.position, new Vector2(xMin, 0), speed * Time.deltaTime);
    _rigidbody.MovePosition(position);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed response!

Answer (score 1):

`Lerp(a, b, t)` interpolates between `a` and `b`.

`t` must be in the range [0,1], so that `Lerp(a, b, 0) = a` and `Lerp(a, b, 1) = b`. Using `speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime` in the place of `t` doesn't make sense.

If you want to move your object from `a` to `b` with a constant speed of `speed` (units per second), you can do:

```
IEnumerator Move(Vector2 a, Vector2 b, float speed){
    float movementDuration = Vector2.Distance(a, b) / speed;
    for(float t = 0; t < 1; t += Time.deltaTime / movementDuration){
        transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(a, b, t);
        yield return null;
    }
    transform.position = b;
}
```

And you can call this method using `StartCoroutine(Move(a, b, speed));`

Be careful not to call this every frame. Call only once and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But as I understand it does not make sense to use Vector2.Lerp in my situation. Because if I specify 0 or 0.1 for t, nothing changes